# how to show array values in list and sublist

Tags: php, loops, logic

Hi I have an array values like 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3

how can we print this in the format most efficiently?

```
<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>0</li>

  <li>
    <ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
   <ul>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
   </ul>
  </li>

 <li>
  <ul>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>3</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

The condition is that 0 must be in the primary list item and any other values must be nested under sub list.

Comment: Your source doesn't validate and doesn't make much sense semantically. Why have so many separate `<ul>`s within the parent `<ul>` (which isn't closed properly)? Also, I think your question needs a little more clarity or it will run the risk of receiving close votes. Have you tried any code at all? What didn't work?

Comment: Please show what you tried, we're not here to do your work for you. It seems like this should just be a loop where you compare the current value to the previous value, and start a new `<ul>` whenever it changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get your question right, each "change" should result in a sublist?

```
$priorElement = null;
echo "<ul>"; // outer ul;
foreach ($values AS $value){
    if ($value != 0){
      if ($priorElement != $value){
        if ($priorElement != null){ 
         echo "</ul></li>";
        }
        echo "<li><ul>";
      }
    }

    echo "<li>$value</li>";

    $priorElement = $value;
}
//final uls
echo "</ul></li></ul>";
```

updated to question.

Produces:

```
<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>0</li>
  <li><ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><ul>
    <li>2</li><li>2</li><li>2</li><li>2</li><li>2</li></ul></li><li><ul><li>3</li></ul></li><li><ul><li>4</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Comment: Good answer execpt you don't have the special case for `0`.

Comment: @Barmer: well, just sort the input then 0 will be topmost. (list looks sorted anyway ?!)

Comment: No, the `0` elements are nested differently than the rest.

Comment: @Barmar: Good point. However the given example is not valid html, so hard to predict the desired outcome.

Comment: The original example was not valid, it looks valid now that he added `<li>` around the nested `<ul>`s.

Comment: @Barmer updated answer. Should work now.

Comment: @DipendraGurung You're welcome. You jsut need to care for the "final" end tags. (for empty list they are "too much").

Answer (score 0):

Use the function

```
array array_unique ( array $array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING ] )
```

https://www.php.net/function.array-unique

to get the unique values with a sorting option.

then use function

```
array array_count_values ( array $array )
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

to get the distinct values count and in loop construct the output.

Comment: this has absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Barmar, I think this is the right way to do. I mean the `array_count_values`

Comment: I think this is answering a completely different question.

Comment: There's nothing in the question about counting things, it's just about turning an array into formatted HTML.

Comment: @Barmar this is two helper function using which he can get the distinct values of the array sorted in order and then the count of occurrence of each value in that array. With that info he can easily recreate that <ul> list.